# Correct Mongodb query equivalent of SQL query

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

What would be the right way to make this exact sql query in Mongodb + Nodejs?

```
select *,
    acos(cos(centerLat * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(centerLon * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lat * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lon * (PI()/180))
     +
     cos(centerLat * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(centerLon * (PI()/180)) *
     cos(lat * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(lon * (PI()/180))
     +
     sin(centerLat * (PI()/180)) *
     sin(lat * (PI()/180))
    ) * 3959 as Dist
from TABLE_NAME
having Dist < radius
order by Dist
```

Code taken from this asnwer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235184/8025329

This is my mongoose Schema:

```
const spotSchema = new Schema({
    latitude: { type: String, required: true },
    longitude: { type: String, required: true },
    spotDate: { type: Date, required: true }
});
```

I expect to retrieve records showing points in a map nearby the user's location. That part I think is down with the formula + sql query. My problem is how to translate that to Mongodb + NodeJs.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it this way:

I took valuable guidance from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291154/8025329

Finally this made it work (it's not final nor polished but solves the main challenge), I'm posting the most essensial parts:

**Mongoose connection** (spacial mention to 'useCreateIndex: true'):

```
mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
```

**Mongoose schema:**

```
const Schema = new Schema({
    loc: { type: Object, index: '2dsphere', required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

**GeoJson object example:**

```
{
loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ longitude, latitude ] },
        category : "location"
      }
```

**Finding nearby places:**

```
MongodbSchema.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
           near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ longitude , latitude ] },
           key: "loc",
           distanceField: "dist.calculated",
           maxDistance: 600,
           query: { category: "location" },
           num: 100,
           spherical: true
        }
      }
   ], function(err, locations){
    if (err) throw err;

    res.send(locations);

   });
```

**Useful links:**
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/